# What is the nozzle extension of merlin engine and rutherford engine made of?

Tags: rockets, propulsion, materials

It is clear from the pictures, that the nozzle extension of Merlin and Rutherford vacuum engine aren't actively cooled.

What is the material of construction for those nozzle extension to withstand higher temperatures, for the entire flight duration?[image: Rutherford engine]

[image: Merlin engine]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Merlin Vacuum engine, the nozzle extension uses a [Niobium alloy](https://web.archive.org/web/20120315135217/http://www2.nspo.org.tw/ASC2008/4th%20Asian%20Space%20Conference%202008/oral/S12-11.pdf). The nozzle is [cooled](http://www.me.umn.edu/labs/tcht/measurements/what.html) via [film cooling](https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-the-SpaceX-Merlin-1D-rocket-engine-have-cooling-channels-on-the-nozzle?share=1):

> The exhaust from the turbopump is injected just above the nozzle extension and helps shield it from the engine exhaust.